# Why does Safari zoom-out on SE after navigating backwards in split-screen view?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, split-view

Oh, the rabbit-holes I find myself in when browsing SE (and in general)...

Not sure if it's a Safari or Stack Exchange bug.. Chrome has the opposite problem.

When following a link on SE and then navigating backwards in Safari split-view (and maybe in normal, manually resized windows), the previous SE page is zoomed-out.

When navigating to a user-profile page on SE, Chrome split-view **does not** zoom out.

[imgur video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF0v0.jpg)

[image: Question View]
[image: Profile View]

(sorry Dmitry Ulupov)